# Generar Codigo alphanumerico PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

actualmente tengo estas variables al momento de llenar un formulario

```
   $codigo_zona =$_POST['codigo_zona'];
  $codigo_sector =$_POST['codigo_sector'];
  $cda_codigo = $codigo_zona."-".$codigo_sector."-".time();
```

Al llenar el formulario y guardar los registros el campo **CDA_CODIGO** me quede con este formato **01-01-"codigo aleatorio"**

01 - codigo_zona
01 - codigo_sector
"codigo aleatorio" - me lo esta generando el time()

este es el resultado que obtengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que el codigo aleatorio que me genera, me genere solamente 3 digitos y no ese monton que me genera el time(), no se que otra funcion habra

Comment: Para eso es la función `random_int()`, ejemplo: `str_pad(random_int(1,999),3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)`.

Comment: Si quieres usar `time()`, podrías obtener tres caracteres del mismo con esto: `substr(time(),-3);` OJO, tratándose de algo aleatorio es más sensando usar las tres últimas cifras porque las mismas cambian con mayor frecuencia que las tres primeras (por eso el `-3` en la función).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Números y Letras
function generarCadenaAleatoria($length = 10)
{
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length / strlen($x)))), 1, $length);
}

//Solo Números
function generarCadenaAleatoriaNumeros($length = 10)
{
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x = '0123456789', ceil($length / strlen($x)))), 1, $length);
}
```

Puedes usar una de esas dos funciones. Por defecto como ves, te generará una cadena de 10 carácteres. Puedes pasarle la longitud que tu quieras.

```
generarCadenaAleatoriaNumeros(3);
```